# Is it a bad idea to use recordId as hashcode?

Tags: .net, hash

Suppose I have a simple DTO object  right out of the database, and the Id is a `recordId` that is definitely unique, is it a good idea then to do the following ?

```
public class DTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (Id == ((DTO)obj).Id);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }
}
```

The reason I doubt it a bit is because I don't see it in code around me, as opposed to code like

```
int hash = 7;
hash = 89 * hash + pageId.hashCode();
hash = 89 * hash + recordId;
return hash;
```

Comment: Hmm... actually I'm currently fighting with a similar issue. FWIW, I think with the exact definition of the ID Property as above (i.e. with a public setter), it cannot safely be used as an attribute for GetHashCode(). One trait of the hashcode of an object is, that it must not change after the object instance has been created.  So, Id should really be set through the constructor and have no public setter.

Comment: I agree, it is an oversimplified class

Answer (score 5):

The contract for a hash code is "two equal objects must have the same hash code". That implies that any fields used in determining equality must be represented in the bits that make up the hash code. Since your equality contract refers only to the `ID`, then that's the only thing required in the hash code.

Comment: That implies that any fields used in determining equality must be represented in the bits that make up the hash code. --> IMO that is not true, it is probably best, but not necessary to honour the contract.  If your hashcode is return 23; for example, two equal objects will have the same hashcode to

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense to me. You say "it's not necessary to honor the contract", then you give an example of a hashcode function returning a constant as an "example" of something. But what is that an example of? It trivially honors the contract, though is a crappy hash function for other reasons. And yes, it is true that two equal objects *must* have the same hash code; that's not subject to opinion. (Otherwise two equal objects can wind up in the same set or as keys in the same map.)

Comment: You misquote me , Please read more carefully : 1. It is necessary to honour the contract of course. 2. two equal objects must have the same hash code , of course again, I am not stating otherwise 3.I only say that using the fields that make up equality do not need to be used in order to honouring the contract. That is simply wrong, I am sorry. To answer your question "What is that an example of" : it's an exmaple of a  crappy hashfunction, but  prove of the fact that a hashfunction do not need to use the fields used in equality in order to honour the contract.

Comment: I interpreted your statement "IMO that is not true, it is probably best, but not necessary to honour the contract." as meaning "it is not necessary to honor the contract," which is, I think, a reasonable interpretation of that sentence (although confusing!). I see now that you meant that "using all fields involved in equality checks in the hash function is not necessary *in order to* honor the contract." So now I also understand your "example"!

Answer (score 2):

A good hash function is supposed to (more or less) randomly distribute the hash values, so that when you put the hash values into a binary tree, you get a good, evenly distributed tree, and not one that is just a linked list down one side.

See here:
http://blogs.oracle.com/kah/entry/the_importance_of_good_hash

But if you never have this need (i.e. you will always be returning records from the database, rather than looking them up from your own binary tree), then using the id as the hash seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: IMO Using just the int is taking care of a perfect(100%) distribution, and why hash an int ? I believe it is just returning the int again for the same reason of perfect distribution.

Comment: It may be perfect distribution if you always load all entities, but if you load only subsets, it's likely that the subset does not have evenly distributed ids.

Comment: See the article.  The only issue is that putting the records of a table into a dictionary (or other binary-search structure) would skew the index, if they were put into the dictionary *in numerical order.*

Comment: @iammichal : I don't believe I get that, each bucket has only one element per definition, no matter the subset

Comment: The solution is to use a data structure that is self-balancing (such as a red-black tree), or put the records into the structure in random order.  But it's all academic if you don't have a need for this.  I only point it out because you asked, and it's the only reason I can think of why an int as a hash might not be a good idea.

Comment: @robert : I have read the article indeed, the copy pasted example in the question is taken from it

Comment: @Robert, I like that pointed out, thanks, I asked indeed, I think discussion around a question/answer is often as interesting as just the straigth answer

Answer (score 1):

Since the int already has a method for getting the hash code, I would just use that one.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Id.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that for?, anyway isn't that just returning the int again?

Answer (score 1):

If your class only contains an integer, you can use that as hash code. That's the same as the implementation of the `Int32.GetHashCode` method that just returns the integer itself.

Comment: Indeed, I thought so, see previous comments,tx

Comment: Since it is a DTO, there would be other fields present as well, but the database would guarantee that the int is unique.